# Determine whether the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2^{n^2}}{n!}$ is convergent or divergent.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

> Determine whether the series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2^{n^2}}{n!},$$ is convergent or divergent.

I know I have to use the ratio test.

Comment: I am afraid it is not comprehensible.

Comment: is it comprehensible now? im new to this website and do not know how to format the questions

Comment: So, what does the ratio test tell you?

Comment: It is fine. Let me fix it with LaTeX.

Comment: it is actually 2 to the power of n squared in the numerator

Comment: Is the formula correct now?

Comment: Yes it is now correct

Answer (score 4):

Yes it diverges, and the simplest test to use is indeed the ratio test:
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{2^{(n+1)^2} n!}{2^{n^2}(n+1)!}=\frac{2^{2n+1}}{n+1}\to \infty,
$$
as $n\to\infty$.

Hence the series diverges.

Comment: Yes, indeed, corrected now.

Comment: It should be divergent.

Comment: Corrected! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative

$$\frac{2^{n^2}}{n!}\ge \frac{2^{n^2}}{n^n}=\left(\frac{2^n}{n}\right)^n\ge \left(\frac{2n}{n}\right)^n=2^n\to \infty$$